# Pivot for a confidence interval

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, definition, pivot

I'm looking at an example in my lecture notes where $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ are iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, where $\sigma^2$ is known. $\bar{X}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$.

The pivot for the confidence interval is given as

$\frac{\bar{X} -\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$

and the notes state that this pivot does **not** depend on $\mu$. I don't really understand how it doesn't. What does it mean for something to 'depend on' something else?

Comment: In this problem Xbar is N(mu, sigma squared/n) and since sigma is known the quantity you give call it Z is N(0,1).  In this sense the pivotal doesn't depend on mu and you can make a probability statement about it based on the standard normal distribution.  You choose the endpoints a and b to get P(a<Z<b)= desired confidence level. Then you can invert this expression to give a statement about mu being between Xbar-b sigma/square root of n and Xbar-a sigma/square root of n.  Then you can claim that in repeated sampling an interval constructed in this way will include mu p% of the time.

Comment: continuation Here p is your specified confidence level and and not include mu (1-p)% of the time.  For any fixed number of replicated samples the statement is approximate. Note that if sigma were unknown the quantity would not be pivotal and the sample standard deviation would need to be used to make it pivotal but now instead of N(0,1) being the reference distribution it is a t with n-1 degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as a function it certainly do depend on $\mu$, simply since the expression for the pivot $$
   \frac{\bar{X} -\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}
$$ do contain $\mu$. So in what sense do it not depend on $\mu$? To understand you need to check the definition of a pivot: It is a function of *data and model parameters* which have a *distribution* which do not depend on the unknown model parameters. That means that the pivot has a known probability distribution, and that is what makes the probability calculations in constructing the confidence interval work.

So the answer to your question is: The pivot has a probability distribution which do not depend on $\mu$.